# Could not plot multiple horizontal bar side by side

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, bar-chart

I would like to plot multiple horizontal bar charts sharing the same y-axis. To elaborate, I have 4 dataframes, each representing a bar chart. I want to use these dataframes to plot 2 horizontal bar charts at the left and another 2 at the right. Right now, I am only able to display one horizontal bar chart at left and right. Below are my desired output, code, and error

[image: Desired Output]

```
data1 = {
'age': ['20-24 Years', '25-29 Years', '30-34 Years', '35-39 Years', '40-44 Years', '45-49 Years'],
'single_value': [97, 75, 35, 19, 15, 13]
}

data2 = {
'age': ['20-24 Years', '25-29 Years', '30-34 Years', '35-39 Years', '40-44 Years', '45-49 Years'],
'single_value': [98, 79, 38, 16, 15, 13]
}

data3 = {
'age': ['20-24 Years', '25-29 Years', '30-34 Years', '35-39 Years', '40-44 Years', '45-49 Years'],
'single_value': [89, 52, 22, 16, 12, 13]
}

data4 = {
'age': ['20-24 Years', '25-29 Years', '30-34 Years', '35-39 Years', '40-44 Years', '45-49 Years'],
'single_value': [95, 64, 27, 18, 15, 13]
}

df_male_1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
df_male_2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)
df_female_1 = pd.DataFrame(data3)
df_female_2 = pd.DataFrame(data4)

fig, axes = plt.subplots(ncols=2, sharey=True, figsize=(12,12))

axes[0].barh(df_male_1['age'], df_male_1['single_value'], align='center', 
color='red', zorder=10)

axes[0].barh(df_male_2['age'], df_male_2['single_value'], align='center', 
color='blue', zorder=10)

axes[0].set(title='Age Group (Male)')

axes[1].barh(df_female_1['age'], df_female_1['single_value'], 
align='center', color='pink', zorder=10)

axes[1].barh(df_female_2['age'], df_female_2['single_value'], 
align='center', color='purple', zorder=10)

axes[1].set(title='Age Group (Female)')

axes[0].invert_xaxis()
axes[0].set(yticks=df_male_1['age'])
axes[0].yaxis.tick_right()

for ax in axes.flat:
    ax.margins(0.09)
    ax.grid(True)

fig.tight_layout()
fig.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.09)
plt.show()
```

Error output
[image: Error output]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that currently your bars are overlapping each other because they are `center` aligned by default. To get the desired figure, you have to align them at the edges. To have them adjacent to each other, you have to use negative and positive heights (horizontal width of bars). You can choose the value of `height` as per needs

Following is the modified code (only showing relevant part)

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(ncols=2, sharey=True, figsize=(12,12))

axes[0].barh(df_male_1['age'], df_male_1['single_value'], align='edge', height=0.3, 
             color='red', zorder=10)

axes[0].barh(df_male_2['age'], df_male_2['single_value'], align='edge', height=-0.3,
             color='blue', zorder=10)

axes[0].set(title='Age Group (Male)')

axes[1].barh(df_female_1['age'], df_female_1['single_value'], align='edge',height=0.3, 
             color='pink', zorder=10)

axes[1].barh(df_female_2['age'], df_female_2['single_value'], align='edge', height=-0.3, 
             color='purple', zorder=10)
```

[image]